# How make sidebar slide inside of a div and not the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the sidebar slide I am using : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/453ezj7t/)

I want to be able to make the sidebar slide inside of a particular div, and not inside of the body.

for instance:

```
<style>
div.windowmain {
height:50%;
width:50%;
border:1px solid black;}

</style>


<body>
  <div class="windowmain">
  </div>

  <div class="therest">
  </div>
</body>
```

I want the sidebar to slide inside of the windowmain.

PS : It's not that I want the ul's parent element to be a div, no. I want the sidebar to slide inside of a smaller div, and not slide on all over the body.

**#update 1**

---

ti be best clear,
Instead of this

[image]

I want this ;

[image]

Comment: You've already wrapped the menu in a ul, right?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Wrap the ul in a div?

Comment: Do you mean this way http://jsfiddle.net/453ezj7t/10/?  It's not that I want ul's parent element to be a div,but I want it to slide inside of a small div, and not slide on all over the body

Comment: You might know what you mean, but we don't have a clue. Do you mean you want the menu to push content over, or appear on top of content, or something else?

Comment: Oh thank you for your comment, I'll update my question with pictures so you get my idea.

Comment: I've still been trying to fix the problem but it's kind of hard to find the solution..

Comment: Thank you for the time you are putting in my question mr @Bokdem. I'm still struggling as well.

Ps : Check the updates.

Comment: FINALLY, i think i have found the solution!

Comment: I'm excited! post it already :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a pretty while, i think i somehow have found the solution.
I will explain the solution step by step.

**First of all:**
Wrap the whole ul-menu called "side-menu" in a div.

**Second step:**
Remove the 'position:fixed;' CSS-styling from the "side-menu"

**Third step:**
Now style the div which wraps the ul with something like this:

```
.menu-wrapper{
    position:fixed;
    width:250px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Now style the wrapper div of the ul to your own needs.

[Here i've updated the jsFiddle you provided us.](http://jsfiddle.net/453ezj7t/13/)

I hope this helps you out, good luck with further development!

Comment: If any other questions, feel free to ask!! :)

Comment: Awesome answer is awesome! I'll fitting this into my project, I'll contact you if I face any other problem. Thanks for the time man!

Comment: Haha great, it was fun searching for a solution! Don't hesitate to ask. Im off to bed now, 24:00 already. Bye!

Comment: Alright man! you'll find comments if I needed help. You dabest.